# Recursive regex to check if string length is a power of 3?

Tags: regex, recursion

I'm attempting to create a regex pattern that will only match strings containing only periods (.) with a length that is a power of 3. Obviously I could manually repeat length checks against powers of 3 up until the length is no longer feasible, but I would prefer a short pattern.

I wrote this python method to help explain what I want to do:

```
#n = length
def check(n):
    if n == 1:
        return True
    elif n / 3 != n / 3.0:
        return False
    else:
        return check(n / 3)
```

To clarify, the regex should only match `.`, `...`, `.........`, `...........................`, (length 1, 3, 9, 27) etc.

I've read up on [regex recursion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html), making use of `(?R)` but I haven't been able to put anything together that works correctly.

Is this possible?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Updated my post to clarify, should only contain periods. Ex: `...` (3), `.........`, (9) etc

Comment: Yes, I see, and that is not possible to do with regex. It has no `pow` "power" :(

Comment: I would be astonished if this was possible. What makes you think it is?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done *using regex* (handles any character, not just period):

```
def length_power_three(string):

    regex = r"."

    while True:
        match = re.match(regex, string)

        if not match:
            return False

        if match.group(0) == string:
            return True

        regex = r"(?:" + regex + r"){3}"
```

But I understand you really want to know if it can be done with a *single* regex.

UPDATE

I forgot that you asked for a *recursive* solution:

```
def length_power_three(string, regex = r"."):
    match = re.match(regex, string)

    if not match:
        return False

    if match.group(0) == string:
        return True

    return length_power_three(string, r"(?:" + regex + r"){3}")
```